# NSDate format in iOS 4.1

Tags: ios4, nsdate, nsdateformatter

[NSDate date]in iOS 4.0 used to return date in the format:
2010-09-15 09:28:26 +0530

but now in iOS 4.1 it returns the date in the format:
2010-09-15 09:28:26 GMT

In my application it is leading to lots of problems.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
YPK

Comment: Show example code that you are using to "get the date" ... and (more likely the problem)... show code that you are using to "display the date".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank for your replies. I googled about the problem and somewhere I found that NSDate has a bug in iOS 4.1. So I solved the problem using following method

```
- (NSString *)formattedStringUsingFormat:(NSString *)dateFormat
{
    NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    [formatter setCalendar:cal];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSString *ret = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [formatter release];
    [cal release];
    return ret;
}
```

and I passed the format as

```
[self formattedStringUsingFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

In iOS2.x and 3.x the NSDate description/datefromstring function returns:
2010-09-24 17:30:00 - 0700

in iOS 4.1 it returns this:
2010-09-25 00:30:00 GMT

You could submit a bug to apple.