# Converting a date format in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How can i convert the following date "Sun Jul 17 07:48:34 +0000 2011"
to the following format "2011-07-17 07:48:34"?

I used `NSDateFormatter` as shown below but it didnt work. It gives null as a result.

```
NSDateFormatter *objDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[objDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[objDateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you used with NSDateFormatter?

Comment: [NSDate format in iOS 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716384/nsdate-format-in-ios-4-1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Convert date string to a relative time stamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902950/iphone-convert-date-string-to-a-relative-time-stamp)

Answer (score 71):

You've got your Date Format wrong for the style of Date you are passing in. Here is a document explaining the different modifiers: [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

To parse the Date "Sun Jul 17 07:48:34 +0000 2011", you'd need a Format like so:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
```

To get it into the following format: "2011-07-17 07:48:34", here is the full code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];

// Convert to new Date Format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: A problem ... it works fine on simulator but it doesnt work on real device ?

Comment: What problem do you have on the Device? Does it give an error? Crash? You need to describe your problem...

Comment: it gives null at converting at any step ... but on simulator it gives the exact result
for example date equals null , new date null
but on simulator it works perfectly 
i tried it on two devices ... the same problem

Comment: If it works on the Simulator but not the device then it may be another issue with your other code. I've used this exact code with both the Simulator and Device multiple times in my projects and I've only seen issues where the dateFormat is incorrect. Maybe post your Project or some more code.

Comment: NSString *sStatusDate= [objStatusDic valueForKey:@"created_at"];
        
        NSDateFormatter *objDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [objDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy"];
        
        NSDate *objDate  = [objDateFormatter dateFromString:sStatusDate];
        
        [objDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        objStatus.StatusDate = [objDateFormatter stringFromDate:objDate];

Comment: Well if both dates are null, it could possibly be that the value of sStatusDate is null on the device? Do an NSLog on sStatusDate and post the output

Answer (score 2):

If sDate is your string that's in the format "Sun Jul 17 07:48:34 +0000 2011", you have to convert that into a NSDate. Then, you can use a second NSDateFormatter to convert this date into your desired format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

If you need to figure out the string needed to convert, this site has a great reference:
http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

e.g. "Sun Jul 17 07:48:34 +0000 2011" can be parsed with

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
```

As a bit of advice, non-standard dates like "Jul" (should be July) can make problems here. It's faster to just convert the needed parts in plain C, with strftime().
See the reference: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/rzan5mst263.htm

You can then convert the unix timestamp back in a NSDate with

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]
```

Using C for date/time parsing is usually up to 10x faster. NSDateFormatter is a slow dog.

Comment: nice link with date format patterns - very helpfull