# iOS - Restkit: How to deal with xml datetime

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, xml-parsing, restkit

I'm using Restkit to consume a web service that sends back XML. Some of the elements are the datetime type. It looks like Restkit wants to treat these as NSDictionary. Is there a simpler way to handle this? Maybe some way to just get the text between the tags?

Here's an of what I'm talking about. XML like this:

```
<lastRenewedDate xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2012-09-18T09:53:00-04:00</lastRenewedDate>
```

Seems to be interpreted by Restkit like this:

```
lastRenewedDate =     {
    text = "2012-09-18T09:53:00-04:00";
    "xmlns:xs" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    "xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    "xsi:type" = "xs:dateTime";
};
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm asking if there's a way for Restkit to directly map that text between the tags:

```
2012-09-18T09:53:00-04:00
```

directly to an NSString rather than mapping it to an NSDictionary and me having to get that text out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, BUT to get the time as a NSString-object you can do this

```
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [[[NSArray objectAtIndex:*SOME INDEX*] objectForKey:@"lastRenewedDate"] objectForKey:@"text"];
```

, where dateFormatter is a NSDateFormatter-object

You can look up how to use dateFormats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724180/converting-a-date-format-in-objective-c)

Comment: This gives me an easy way to deal with it though.