# How to format the date in different styles?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have to format the date string:  **Tuesday 4 December 2012**

into this format:

**2012-12-04**

Im using this code, but I don't know which correct **setDateFormat** string should I use to get the required result.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dddd d M YYYY"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:tempDate];
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a date format in objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724180/converting-a-date-format-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yyyy-MM-dd (assuming the 12 in your example is the month)

It's all explained in the [NSDateFormatter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) under "Use Format Strings To Specify Custom Formats"

Answer (score 1):

Used the following code to get the task done!

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE d MMMM yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:tempDate];

    // Converts date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
    NSString* formattedDateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```