# UIDatePicker default day is today not what it is set to

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIDatePicker` which the first date it is set to (and beginning of the range) is `2013-08-30 00:00:00 +0000`.

When selecting a date through an IBAction **WITHOUT** scrolling the UIDatePicker the date that comes up from `datePicked = [datePicker date];` is todays date and not `2013-08-30 00:00:00 +0000`.

Is there a way I can prevent this behaviour from occurring, I have tried last night for a few hours to fix it but I cannot find a way.

Comment: set datepicker.date=yourDate;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set default date to DatePicker,

```
    NSDateFormatter *formater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date= [formater dateFromString:@"2013-08-30"]
    [datePicker setDate:date];
```

Comment: Ahh thanks! How can I use `setDateFormat` to include the hour, minuit, second and z (+0000)?

Comment: @Josh Boothe:set like this,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: once refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724180/converting-a-date-format-in-objective-c