# Convert time from milliseconds to human readable date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, time, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this time in milliseconds that i am receiving in an XML feed, and i need to display this time in any appropriate form, that anyone can understand.

can anyone guide me on how to achieve such behavior?

thank you.

Note: the millis time that i am getting is in UNIX time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `NSDate`'s `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` method by dividing your timestamp by `1000.0`.

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp / 1000.0];
```

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716384/nsdate-format-in-ios-4-1) for more details on formatting.

Comment: I am getting `16 jan 1970` for every date i try to convert using these methods. But when i use an online conversion tool, I am getting the real results....

Comment: Huh. Didn't you have the time in milliseconds?

Comment: That is what I thought at first. The feed I am getting is a feed from facebook, and after trying some online conversion tools with positive results, i concluded that it was in millis. weird.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `NSDate` object with your interval and then use an `NSDateFormatter` object to turn that into a display value, like this:

```
- (void)displayDate:(double)unixMilliseconds {
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixMilliseconds / 1000.];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSLog("The date is %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

Obviously you should allocate the formatter once and keep it around if you do this a lot.

Comment: It's cool, I didn't notice the link in his answer on how to format it so I tried giving a more complete answer.